# I would like not to use root as global

Tags: c++, avl-tree

Hello I am writing an avl tree and I have one issue . I am currently having a root as global since I use it in the class as well as in main , how can I write it without having it global?

```
struct avl_node {
    int data;
    struct avl_node *left;
    struct avl_node *right;
}*root;

class avlTree {
    public:
        int height(avl_node *temp)
        {
            int h = 0;
            if (temp != NULL)
            {
                int l_height = height (temp->left);
                int r_height = height (temp->right);
                int max_height = max (l_height, r_height);
                h = max_height + 1;
            }
            return h;
        }

        int diff(avl_node *temp)
        {
            int l_height = height (temp->left);
            int r_height = height (temp->right);
            int b_factor= l_height - r_height;
            return b_factor;
        }

        avl_node *rr_rotation(avl_node *parent)
        {
            avl_node *temp;
            temp = parent->right;
            parent->right = temp->left;
            temp->left = parent;
            return temp;
        }       

        avl_node *ll_rotation(avl_node *parent)
        {
            avl_node *temp;
            temp = parent->left;
            parent->left = temp->right;
            temp->right = parent;
            return temp;
        }

        avl_node *lr_rotation(avl_node *parent)
        {
            avl_node *temp;
            temp = parent->left;
            parent->left = rr_rotation (temp);
            return ll_rotation (parent);
        }

        avl_node *rl_rotation(avl_node *parent)
        {
            avl_node *temp;
            temp = parent->right;
            parent->right = ll_rotation (temp);
            return rr_rotation (parent);
        }

        avl_node* balance(avl_node *temp)
        {
            int bal_factor = diff (temp);
            if (bal_factor > 1)
            {
                if (diff (temp->left) > 0)
                    temp = ll_rotation (temp);
                else
                    temp = lr_rotation (temp);
            }
            else if (bal_factor < -1)
            {
                if (diff (temp->right) > 0)
                    temp = rl_rotation (temp);
                else
                    temp = rr_rotation (temp);
            }
            return temp;
        }

        avl_node* insert(avl_node *root, int value)
        {
            if (root == NULL)
            {
                root = new avl_node;
                root->data = value;
                root->left = NULL;
                root->right = NULL;
                return root;
            }
            else if (value < root->data)
            {
                root->left = insert(root->left, value);
                root = balance (root);
            }
            else if (value >= root->data)
            {
                root->right = insert(root->right, value);
                root = balance (root);
            }
            return root;
        }

        void display(avl_node *ptr, int level)
        {
            int i;
            if (ptr!=NULL)
            {
                display(ptr->right, level + 1);
                printf("\n");
                if (ptr == root)
                    cout<<"Root -> ";
                for (i = 0; i < level && ptr != root; i++)
                    cout<<"        ";
                cout<<ptr->data;
                display(ptr->left, level + 1);
            }
        }

        void inorder(avl_node *tree)
        {
            if (tree == NULL)
                return;
            inorder (tree->left);
            cout<<tree->data<<"  ";
            inorder (tree->right);
        }

        void preorder(avl_node *tree)
        {
            if (tree == NULL)
                return;
            cout<<tree->data<<"  ";
            preorder (tree->left);
            preorder (tree->right);
        }

        void postorder(avl_node *tree)
        {
            if (tree == NULL)
                return;
            postorder ( tree ->left );
            postorder ( tree ->right );
            cout<<tree->data<<"  ";
        }

        avlTree()
        {
            root = NULL;
        }
};


int main()
{
    int choice, item;
    avlTree avl;
    while (1)
    {
        cout<<"\n---------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"AVL Tree Implementation"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n---------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"1.Insert Element into the tree"<<endl;
        cout<<"2.Display Balanced AVL Tree"<<endl;
        cout<<"3.InOrder traversal"<<endl;
        cout<<"4.PreOrder traversal"<<endl;
        cout<<"5.PostOrder traversal"<<endl;
        cout<<"6.Exit"<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter your Choice: ";
        cin>>choice;
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                system("cls");
                cout<<"Enter value to be inserted: ";
                cin>>item;
                root = avl.insert(root, item);
                break;
            case 2:
                system("cls");
                if (root == NULL)
                {
                    cout<<"Tree is Empty"<<endl;
                    continue;
                }
                cout<<"Balanced AVL Tree:"<<endl;
                avl.display(root, 1);
                break;
            case 3:
                system("cls");
                cout<<"Inorder Traversal:"<<endl;
                avl.inorder(root);
                cout<<endl;
                break;
            case 4:
                system("cls");
                cout<<"Preorder Traversal:"<<endl;
                avl.preorder(root);
                cout<<endl;
                break;
            case 5:
                system("cls");
                cout<<"Postorder Traversal:"<<endl;
                avl.postorder(root);    
                cout<<endl;
                break;
            case 6:
                exit(1);    
                break;
            default:
                system("cls");
                cout<<"Wrong Choice"<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is `root` a node and not an `avlTree` (which should contain a root node)? Then most of those functions operate on the contained `root` instead of needing a parameter.

Comment: I kind of understand what you mean but i am pretty clueless on how to implement it .

Comment: Make `root` a member of the class: `class avlTree{ struct avl_node{...} *root; public: ...methods};`

Comment: @Bogdan one of the basics of Object Oriented Programming: [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29), as in "A language construct that facilitates the bundling of data with the methods (or other functions) operating on that data.".

Comment: @CiaPanMaking the root a member of the class wont solve it since i use root again in the main ? 
crashmstr Ok  .

Comment: @Bogdan the point is that you *don't* refer to a global `root`, but instead just have `avlTree avl;` that *contains* the tree itself, and then would `avl.insert(item);`. You could then have two trees easily, with `avlTree secondTree;`

Comment: As @crashmstr said, you should *not* use `root` in `main()`.The root item is a tree main element, and it should be the `avlTree` class member.  All tree functions that use it should access it as an `avlTree` object member. The only place where you explicitly use `root` is testing for `NULL`—and that should be replaced with a function like `bool avlTree::IsEmpty() { return root == nullptr;}`. ....

Comment: .... If you still wonder, please consider the case of having two or more trees in a program; it is clear that each tree has its own root. Declaring a root node (i.e. an actual **tree**) and a set of its functions (your current class) separately is calling for troubles.

Comment: @CiaPan Yes indeed it was silly to use root for a test , thank you i stil have this line in main though.
root = avl.insert(root, item);

Comment: See my answer for avoiding explicit use of `root`. Additionally consider storing the balance factor *inside* each node (and updating it there after each insert, delete and rotate action). Explicit calculation of `height(node)` causes additional visiting approx. 2N nodes on each action, which makes your tree **worse** (less eficient) than an ordinary linked list!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not explicitly use the tree's `root` in `main()`, and generally outside the tree's methods. To achieve this just make the method

```
    avl_node* insert(avl_node *where, int value)
```

private (or protected, at least) in a class and add a public interface:

```
    void insert(int value)
    {
        root = insert(root, value);
    }
```

Then in main you add items simply by calling

```
    avlTree tree;

    ....
    tree.insert(item);
```

**EDIT** to answer a question asked in a comment.

Functions like `display`, `inorder` etc. should be handled in the same way as `insert`: declare a public, parameterless function to launch the action and a protected method with a parameter to recursively perform it:

```
public:
    void display()     { display(root, 0); }
    void inorder()     { inorder(root); }
    .....

protected:
    void display(avl_node *node, int level)
    {
        if (node!=NULL)
        {
            display(node->right, level + 1);
            if (node == root)
                cout << "Root -> ";
            else
                cout << "        ";
            cout << setw(5*level) << "" << node->data << endl;
            display(node->left, level + 1);
        }
    }

    void inorder(avl_node *node)
    {
        if (node)
        {
            inorder (node->left);
            cout << node->data << "  ";
            inorder (node->right);
        }
    }
```

then use:

```
tree.display();
tree.inorder();
```

Comment: Thank you , now it does make more sense. I have only one more question , what can I do with the in/post/pre orders and the display to stop using root as a parameter .

Comment: thanks , i managed to do it myself anyway but i'll take a look at your interpretation