# binary tree: node not recognized

Tags: c++, binary-tree

Im tryng to programming a binary tree with his function of searching, inserting and delete
but in the main the compiler doesn't recognize "found" and "root", declarated in the header and initialized in the constructor
Here's the code

binarytree.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include "Tree.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Tree a;
    char c;
        while(c!='4'){
            cout<<"Inserisci 1 per inserire un valore nell'albero\n 2 per cercarne un valore\n";
            cout<<"3 per distruggere un valore e tutti i suoi rami\n 4 per uscire";
            cin>>c;
            if(c=='1'){
                                    int n;
                                    cout<<"Inserisci il valore numerico da immettere";
                                    cin>>n;
                                    a.insert(n,a.root);
                                }
            if(c=='2'){
                                    int n;
                                    cout<<"Inserisci il valore numerico da cercare";
                                    cin>>n;
                                    a.search(n,a.root,a.found);
                                    if(a.found==NULL)
                                        cout<<"Elemento non trovato";
                                }
            if(c=='3'){
                                    int n;
                                    cout<<"Inserisci il valore numerico da eliminare con tutti i suoi rami";
                                    cin>>n;
                                    a.search(n,a.root,a.found);
                                    if(a.found==NULL)
                                        cout<<"Elemento non trovato";
                                    a.destroy_tree(a.found);
                                }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Tree.h

```
#ifndef TREE_H_
#define TREE_H_

#include <cstddef>
class Tree {
private:
         struct node{
            node *right;
            node *left;
            int data;
            };
public:
         Tree(){
            root = NULL;
            found = NULL;
         }
    void destroy_tree(node*);
    void insert(int, node*);
    void search(int, node*,node*);
    node *root;
    node *found;
};

#endif /* TREE_H_ */
```

Tree.cpp

```
#include "Tree.h"
#include <cstddef>

void Tree::destroy_tree(node *leaf){
    if(leaf!=NULL){
        Tree::destroy_tree(leaf->left);
        Tree::destroy_tree(leaf->right);
        delete leaf;
    }
}

void Tree::insert(int key, node *leaf){
   if(leaf==NULL)
    leaf->data=key;
   else{
  if(key<leaf->data)
  {
    if(leaf->left!=NULL)
     insert(key, leaf->left);
    else
    {
      leaf->left = new node;
      leaf->left->data=key;
      leaf->left->left=NULL;    //Sets the left child of the child node to null
      leaf->left->right=NULL;   //Sets the right child of the child node to null
    }
  }
  else if(key>=leaf->data)
  {
    if(leaf->right!=NULL)
      insert(key, leaf->right);
    else
    {
      leaf->right=new node;
      leaf->right->data=key;
      leaf->right->left=NULL;  //Sets the left child of the child node to null
      leaf->right->right=NULL; //Sets the right child of the child node to null
    }
  }
}
}
void Tree::search(int key, node *leaf, node* found){
  if(leaf!=NULL){
    if(key==leaf->data)
      found = leaf;
    if(key<leaf->data)
      search(key, leaf->left, found);
    else
      search(key, leaf->right, found);
  }
  else found = NULL;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: For question (and answer) on **not** using explicit `root` pointer variable see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326969/i-would-like-not-to-use-root-as-global/

Answer (score 0):

The "root" & "found" are class attributes.
From the main function, as they are public, you must access them like this : 
    `Tree a;`
    `a.root;`

And yes of course, you should avoid to use these 2 attributes as public. Make them private to access them only from the Tree class.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now it works but the insert function crash after inserting. I tought was cause by the NULL root node so I've modified the code adding the condition but it keep crashing

Comment: I think you should first modify your code to remove the public attributes.
Make them private and update the insert method to directly modify the root attribute of the Tree object.

Also you made several mistakes here :
    if(leaf==NULL)
        leaf->data=key;
    else{...}

1 / you forget to closing } before the else
2 / leaf is NULL ! (you juste made the test whithin the if), so you cannot write leaf->data !